# Map nested fields to top level fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an Elasticsearch instance where it is initialized using a JSON file containing the field definitions. I then populate a list of POCO objects and using NEST call the IndexManyAsync to insert or update the documents.  All this works great.  I now have a small list of dynamic fields that will be added to the index over time.  I am trying to come up with a solution that does not involve recompiling my POCO class whenever a new field needs to be added.  The only solution I've come up with is to add an "additionalInfo" Dictionary field to the POCO object.  The downside to this approach is the dynamic fields are added as sub-fields to additionalInfo:

```
"additionalInfo" : {
    "$type" : "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib]], mscorlib",
    "hello" : [
      "WORLD",
      "Everyone!"
    ],
    "foo" : [
      "BAR"
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to have Elasticsearch ignore "additionalInfo" so the sub-fields become root-level fields?  Or is there a better way to model dynamic fields in a POCO class?